# Firebase custom event parameter limits

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

As documented [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en), Firebase has a parameter limit of 10 custom text parameter per project.

We are struggling with these limitations. In Google Analytics we used to have a lot of events with custom information. Like:

```
Event Name | Param 1 | Param 2

Sign In | Type (Email / Google / Facebook)

Open Tab | Tab Name

Change setting | Setting name (Notifications / Enable features)

Change profile | Value changed (Name / Profile picture / Language)

Edit Item | Item Key (e.g. Bread) | Edit Type (change Name / Quantity / Image)
```

And the list goes on. But this results in much more custom text parameters than the 10 allowed. So I wonder if I totally misunderstand the whole concept.

How do other track their events to not run into this limits?

Answer (score 2):

The limit that you mentioned is only for **reporting purposes**. Reporting purposes mean that you register your custom property in Firebase console and it is displayed in your UI - you can have up to 50 of that kind of properties.

But in general you can have a lot of custom properties - 25 for each custom event. And you can have 500 custom events, which means you can have 25 * 50 = **12 500 custom parameters**.

If they are not included in reporting they will not be displayed in Firebase console data analysis (charts, etc.), but they are still stored and you can access them via BigQuery - if you want to do some analysis on your own.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know - so it's supposed to be used via BigQuery.
But still, why would google build such a sophisticated UI but not allow users to properly use it?

Comment: I know what you mean. On the other hand Firebase Analytics is still quite fresh product so it might be just initial phase to see which features are really needed and which can be properly handled at scale. And nothing hurts as much as *decreasing* limit, so probably it's just better to start "too small" than "too large"?